# CLI (linux) rendering cycles, and cpu + GPU

Tags: rendering, command-line

I'm currently testing my first try at the rendering cycles on the CLI in Linux. this is the script  I wrote for it. I was wondering what about using the GPU along with cpu.Laptop Specs

```
CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2760QM CPU @ 2.40GHz
RAM 15993 MB : 1614 : 151
Graphics Card [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]

#!/bin/bash

#executable
Blender=/media/data/blender-2.79-5480de3fca8-linux-glibc219-x86_64/blender 
#file to render
file=/media/data/Charlotte_Zone_video/CZ_Shorter_version/BlenderNightly/Charlotte_Zone_Marque_SS_ShorterVersion_08a2a.blend
#output images to
output=/media/projects/Charlotte_Zone_video/CLI_CZ_Shorter_version_middle/Charlotte_Zone_SuperStar_ShorterVersion_Marque_08a-####
render_type=CYCLES
cores=2
#Frame Numbers
start=2355
finish=2400

 "$Blender" -b "$file" -o "$output" -E "$render_type" -s "$start" -e "$finish" -t "$cores" -a
```

reference page:
[Blender CLI](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/workflows/command_line.html)